# How can I share code between a Shared Universal project and a Background Task?

Tags: c#, generics, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Right now I have a Universal Project which contains mostly business logic and models.
These I can access from both the Windows Phone project AND the Windows project.

But when I add a Background Task, I would like to access that shared logic as well, because otherwise I'd have to duplicate most of my code in my background task.

I know you can do "Add as Link", but this causes compilation errors like this:

> Method 'MyProject.Model.Playlist.Tracks.get()' has a parameter of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' in its signature. Although this generic type is not a valid Windows Runtime type, the type or its generic parameters implement interfaces that are valid Windows Runtime types. Consider changing the type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' in the method signature to one of the following types instead: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.

These can be worked away, by either using the **`internal`** keyword on functions / classes where needed, or **converting** my code to the suggested types.

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible in my case, because SQLiteNet-Extensions uses the properties to determine its relations, and only certain types are supported (`List`, `array`, and I added `ObservableCollection`).

So I'm looking for a way to share code between my Shared project and my BackgroundTask, without getting into the "valid Windows Runtime type" errors.

Comment: Can't you just make a Universal class library? You can reference it in both WinRT app, WP app, and Windows Runtime component (which is the type of the Background Task project, I guess?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share code between Windows Phone and Windows 8 app projects by creating a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714086(v=vs.105).aspx). You then need to add a reference to the library in each of the projects which should use it.

Unfortunately you *will* be constrained to the common denominators across the target frameworks. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx#features) details these. Available members for PCL and your target frameworks will appear in Intellisense.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I lose the benefits of using a Shared project at all?

Comment: No, because there's no point sharing code which won't run on both platforms.

Comment: I've made a PCL of my code, and the code gets shared. Thanks for your solution!